# Is there a way to fetch username from Microsoft teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have deployed my bot on Microsoft teams channel. Is there a way I can fetch logged in user email id for my bot?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, follow the approach used by [AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot) to authenticate the user and then get the email address from the Microsoft Account profile of the user. However if you're just looking for a way to uniquely identify users, you can simply key the data in your data-store based on the From property of the [incoming activities](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html).